# Whats the easiest way to animate a toy house being built from the ground up?

Tags: animation

I've modeled this toy house and now would like to animate it being built from the ground up brick by brick. Almost as if the pieces are raining down into place. I could animate each piece individually but I'm hoping there's a more efficient way. Maybe an add on? Any ideas would be of great help.

[image: Partial Story Board]
[image: Complete]

Comment: not sure to understand your need. But mesh deform modifier ?

Comment: I added an image that's more descriptive.

Comment: ok... just like the bricks are falling one by one or by level ?

Comment: so... shape keys ?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use python to animate the individual blocks.

I would pick a landing time based on the z coordinate of the block and a little bit of randomness (but not so much randomness that a block with a different Z coordinate could land before one below it).

http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/sweep-animate-size.html includes some examples of setting keyframes like

```
    fr = obj_to_frame_f(obj)

    obj.scale =(0,0,0)
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='scale', frame=fr-timescale-timescale2)
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='scale', frame=fr+timescale+timescale2)
    s = 0.9
    obj.scale=(s,s,s)
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='scale', frame=fr-timescale)
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='scale', frame=fr+timescale)
```

Although you'll be animating `data_path='location'` instead of scale.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of an explode modifier + a particle system can give you a good starting point, if you play the simulation in reverse.

you have no control on the order of the pieces

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Using a mesh deform modifier, you can play on the "object" of the modifier to displace your mesh.
And so make an animation with it (for instance a shape key on the cube object in the pictures below).

Not sure this is what you asked for... but...

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok.. bad answer considering the edit of the question